# Interpretation of sensitivity analysis provided by tgp package

Tags: r, sensitivity-analysis

I have a question about the interpretation of the sensitivity analysis I obtained by R's tgp package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tgp/vignettes/tgp2.pdf) as can be seen below. The relation between the six inputs and the model response are shown below.

The influence of the parameters on the response is clearly visible, however, what is not totally clear to me, are the values of the response on the vertical axes. How to interpret this is the value of the response is negative and not positive?

For example an increasing VF has a negative influence on the response. VEs as well but here the values in the vertical axis are negative, what exactly does this mean? What is then the difference?

Thanks!

[image]